# How do I dynamically change Form Post URL?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, post, get

I want to make the results of an ASP.NET form POST "bookmarkable", and I'm thinking of using query parameters to accomplish this.

The idea is that a user will visit http://domath.com and they will type in a math problem, and view the results.  The query and results are visible at http://domath.com?ProblemID={some guid here}

The only part I don't really know is how do I change the target of the form URL since I'm using a POST instead of a GET..

Here are the options I came up with, and I'm not sure what is practical

- Submit form as usual, server redirects to a URL with the new parameters attached
- Use a webservice or callback to get new URL.  Javascript then updates form target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option is the easiest and most common. It follows the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) model, which avoids double form submission in addition to letting you bookmark the resulting page.